# setting language in a Locale

Tags: java, runtime, locale

I would like to know why the following compiles:

```
Locale aLocale = new Locale.Builder().setLanguage("trollolo").setRegion("CA").build();
System.out.println(aLocale.getLanguage());
```

Since "trollolo" is not a language. Why does it not return a run time exception but instead it "trollolo" gets even returned when called `getLanguage()`?

Comment: You just invented a new language which doesn't have an ISO code yet, and Java happily lets you use it in your application. Isn't that cool? :-)

Comment: @JBNizet I will boast about it during a job interview, super proud of it sdpflspadgkosdkaf ;P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is permitted behavior. From the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html)

> The Builder only checks if an individual field satisfies the syntactic requirement (is well-formed), but does not validate the value itself.

The syntax (IETF BCP 47) is defined in [Tags for Identifying Languages](http://tools.ietf.org/html/bcp47)

Comment: When converting something in "trololo" language eventually it will give a runtimeexception?

Comment: Nope, seems youre allowed to do this, on the other hand if you specified something that was syntactically incorrect e.g. "trollolo123" then it would throw an exception